# How to create MFTF testing for custom module in magento 2.4.3-p1

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, mftf, magento2marketplace, magento2.4.3.p1

Does marketplace add custom extension mftf (Magento Functional Testing Framework) fail how to solve this issue?

> Marketplace issue report :

https://prnt.sc/22quodr

AdminCreateAndEditBundleProductSettingsTest : Broken